# How to prevent cloning the value when cloning textarea with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to clone a div on button click so that it basically added another field option to the blog post. I have everything working fine except one thing. When I clone the first div(acting kind of like a template) is also clones the val of the textarea. I want it to clone the div without any of the values within the input and textarea so it just shows the placeholder. I will provide my code below. Any help would be great!

The div I cloning

```
 <div class="multi-fields">
     <div class="multi-field">
         <div class="col-12 padding-top-thirty">
            <h1>Click To Edit Title</h1>
        </div>
        <input type="file" name="file_array[]">
        <textarea name="file_array_caption[]" placeholder="Add Caption Here......"></textarea>
        <button  name="delete" type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>


  // add new field to the blog editor
  $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
      var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
      $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
          var clone = $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).val("").end();
      });
      $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
          if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
              $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
      });
  });
```

Comment: Why can't you just clone and then clear the text?

Comment: i tried but it wont work for some reason

Comment: If that is the div you are cloning, where none of the controls have an initial value when the page is first loaded, I would clone the div on document.ready — _first thing_ before any values are loaded.  Keep that cloned DOM subtree aside, do not add it to the page DOM. Then when you press the button, clone _that_ and add the just-cloned subtree to the page DOM.

Comment: Thank you for the adivce, I have just done exactly that because I added an "add image" option as well so it casues issues without doing what u said.

Comment: Cool -- have a look at the HTML5 `<template>` tag too. Good brief intro: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  You don't always need to do all the things in a single line.

```
  $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
      var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
      $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
          var clone = $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true);
          clone.find('input').val('');    // Clear all inputs in the clone object
          clone.find('textarea').val(''); // Clear all textareas in the clone object
          clone.appendTo($wrapper);
      });
      $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
          if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
              $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
      });
  });
```

Comment: Why is `clone()` still not working with `textarea` in firefox? I'm using jQuery 1.11 , but they say it would have been fixed in 1.4... ??? https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3016

Comment: clone.find('textarea').val(''); helps me. the issue is  when i clone the parent, the value in the paent field also cloned. now using  clone.find('textarea').val(''); this line , my problem solved